# Are/were anti-US murals and posters in Pyongyang gone for good since 2018?

Tags: united-states, north-korea, propaganda

NY Post [claimed in 2018](https://nypost.com/2018/06/23/north-korea-erasing-most-anti-us-propaganda/):

> Gone are the posters depicting the U.S. as a “rotten, diseased, pirate nation” and promising “merciless revenge” on American forces for an imagined attack on the totalitarian country.
>
> Murals, banners and posters displayed throughout the capital, Pyongyang, have for decades depicted the U.S. as a brutal, imperialist aggressor hell-bent on destroying the North Korean regime. South Korea and Japan were also frequently targeted as willing allies of the U.S.
>
> But things started to take an Orwellian turn in the run-up to Kim’s June 12 summit with President Donald Trump, with the old posters vanishing since then.
>
> “All the anti-American posters I usually see around Kim Il-sung Square and at shops, they’ve all just gone,” Rowan Beard, a tour manager at Young Pioneer Tours, told Reuters. “In five years working in North Korea, I’ve never seen them completely disappear before.”
>
> Infamous posters and postcards showing North Korean missiles on their way to Washington are a thing of the past.

Did North Korea bring them back after negotiations went south or was the propaganda tune-change more permanent (meaning lasting up to 2023)?

Comment: This might be a question better suited for Skeptics, but it would be very Orwellian if true. "The USA is not our enemy. They are our friends and have ALWAYS been our friends."

Comment: @ouflak: I'm not challenging the claim that they were removed at one point. And the quote isn't saying/predicting they were never coming back. So not on-topic for Skeptics. I'm curious how long the 'détente' lasted, propaganda-wise. This was a common tactic in other Soviet-sphere countries BTW.

Comment: @ouflak: But if the claim in the quote is false, and they were never actually removed, a frame-challenge answer would be fine too, of course. But my experience with propaganda in communist countries is that at least on the level of newspaper articles (published there), what the quote says did usually happen. I.e. they'd lay off blasting capitalism a bit when Westerners were about to visit.